Синонимизировать метки [carousel] и [карусель]
Предлагаю синонимизировать следующие метки:

carousel (50 вопроса) описания нет
карусель (47 вопроса) описания нет

Основная метка - карусель

658 вопроса - точно не 47?

уже поздно проверять, но да, вероятно ошиблась

updating post history, 58 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 50 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 44 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'carousel': [carousel] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 91
tag remapping of [карусель] and [carousel] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
2 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!

